# How to get specific property of an object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js, backend

So I'm sending data properly to mongo and data (user input information), which is correctly held in backend. In console I'm getting interceptor that tells me that data is received from Mongo DB, but how to properly get those properties (user's email, title of photo and url blob) or 'data'? So it can be seen as individual data (email, title...) and not as the whole object like it can be seen  in console now.

--THIS IS IN MY VUE--

```
dohvatiObjavu(){
      
        this.objava = Objave.dohvati_objavu();

        console.log("Current post " + this.objava);
     
        }
},
```

-- THIS IS IN SERVICES--

```
   [let Objave = {
    async dohvati_objavu() {

        let response = await Service.get(/galerija)

        let data = response.data;

        console.log("Current posts in services: "+data.naslov)

            return {
                id: data._id,
                email: data.email,
                naslov: data.naslov,
                noviOpisSlike: data.noviOpisSlike,
                slika: data.slikaReference,

            }

    },
}
```

--THIS IS IN BACKEND--

```
app.get ('/galerija', async (req , res) => {
let db = await connect();
let cursor = await db.collection('galerija').find();
let results = await cursor.toArray();

res.json(results);
```

});

-- MY CONSOLE--

[image]

Comment: Can you share what's on your console?

Comment: It's updated with photo of console

Comment: If `response.data` is an array, there will be no `data._id` etc. That object you are returning will have a bunch of `undefined` property values.

Comment: Can you show this in code answer?  how to get this property i need? @ISAE

Comment: In your service: `return data.map(el => {return {
                id: el._id,
                email: el.email,
                naslov: el.naslov,
                noviOpisSlike: el.noviOpisSlike,
                slika: el.slikaReference,
            }});`

Answer (score 1):

`Objave.dohvati_objavu();` is an async function. So you should also await this inside your Vue method `dohvatiObjavu()`.

I created a simplified working example, based on your code:

```js
const Objave = {
  dohvati_objavu: async function() {

    // mock Service.get(/galerija) with Promise.resolve
    const data = await Promise.resolve({
      id: 'mockId',
      email: 'mockEmail',
      naslov: 'mockNaslov',
      noviOpisSlike: 'mockNoviOpisSlike',
      slika: 'mockSlika',
    });

    return {
      id: data._id,
      email: data.email,
      naslov: data.naslov,
      noviOpisSlike: data.noviOpisSlike,
      slika: data.slikaReference
    }
  }
}

const MyVueComponent = class {
  objava = undefined;

  // DOES NOT WORK
  dohvatiObjavu() {
    this.objava = Objave.dohvati_objavu();
    console.log("[dohvatiObjavu] Current post ", this.objava);
  }

  // WORKS 
  async dohvatiObjavu2() {
    this.objava = await Objave.dohvati_objavu(); // <!-- await
    console.log("[dohvatiObjavu2] Current post ", this.objava);
  }
}

const component = new MyVueComponent()
component.dohvatiObjavu();
component.dohvatiObjavu2();
```